# How to submit huge number of small jobs using PBS queue system

Tags: python, bash, perl, process, pbs

I often need to run huge number of small jobs (runs for several minutes) using PBS queue system. These jobs are using same script to work on different input and they often take different time.

Because the number of jobs is so large that the PBS queue cannot handle it very well. And because different jobs take different time, using pbsdsh is not efficient.

So the idea solution will be wrap some number of jobs (for example 100 small job) into one job. This one job can be submitted to a node with 16 cores. On this node, 16 processes (corresponding to 16 small jobs) run parallel on each core. Once one process is finished on a core, new process runs on that core. If I can do this, it will both reduce the number of jobs a lot (100 times) and not waste any computing time.

Does any one have any recommendation solution on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some sample input jobs to understand the clear requirement

Comment: Would job arrays help? [Chapter 9. Job Arrays](http://resources.altair.com/pbs/documentation/support/PBSProUserGuide12.1.pdf#G12.683157)

Comment: Which version of PBS are you using?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov: No. Actually I always use job array. When the number of jobs is huge, the PBS doesn't work very well.

Comment: @dbeer: The version is 2.5.5

Comment: Is it Torque? If it is, a simple solution to this problem would be to upgrade. Torque 4.2.10, 5.0.2, or 5.1.1 all handle far more jobs than 2.5.5, which has a single-threaded server.

Comment: Looks like a job for GNU parallel.

Answer (score 2):

[Snakemake](https://bitbucket.org/johanneskoester/snakemake/wiki/Documentation) might be a good fit in your situation. Take a look at the documentation for the `--cluster` and the `-j N` options. When you run `snakemake` with the `-j N` option it will only submit N number of jobs at a time. Then as each job finishes, it will start a new one.

P